# jqGrid + SqlDataSource Post Back Problem

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sqldatasource, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm using jqGrid in an asp.net page.

It is bound to an SqlDataSource object in the markup file, but I set the SelectCommand of this SqlDataSource on Page_Load in code-behind, ie:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1"  
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FooDatabase %>" > 
    </asp:SqlDataSource>     

    <cc1:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGrid1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
        Width="600px" Height="462px" onsearch="JQGrid1_Searching" 
        PagerSettings-PageSize="20" > 


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand =
            "SELECT [Foo] From [FooTable]", 
    }
```

This works fine.

But when I assign the same SelectCommand in a button click event no data loads into the jqGrid. Ie:

```
    protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand =
            "SELECT [Foo] FROM [FooTable]"
    }
```

I've tried calling JQGrid.DataBind() on postback, but that didnt work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: probably you use commercial version of jqGrid (from http://www.trirand.net/)? Then you should use `jqgrid-asp.net` tag instead of `jqgrid` because your question seems be pure backend problem.

Comment: Ok fixed. It is from trirand, yes. I am using a free version.

Comment: You can use both tags if you want. The question with `jqgrid` are mostly about the client JavaScript part of the jqGrid solutions. I wrote my suggestion about the tags only that the people who can answer on your question will read it.

Comment: Free version is from http://www.trirand.com/blog/ and not from http://www.trirand.net/. The free version is open source **JavaScript solution** and has no SqlServer data binding.

Comment: Ok. Well it works on page_load, not on postback from btn_Submit_Click.

Comment: were you able to load it on button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. Have to assign the sql command inside the grid's DataRequesting event,

```
    protected void JqGrid_Requesting(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridDataRequestEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (Session["Cmd"] != null)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = Session["Cmd"] as string; 
        }
    }
```

See following link : http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=23